# Copy character string to character pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here is a simple program to demonstrate my problem.
I have a function `functionB` which passes pointer to a character array to `functionA`. `functionA` finds the value and stores it to a character array. The content of character array should be copied to character pointer `fdate`. How can I achieve this?

```
int functionB() {
    char fdate[20];
    functionA(&fdate[0]);
    return 0;
}

int functionA(char *fdate) {
    char date[20] = "20 May 2016";
    strcpy(fdate, date);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You certainly don't want to copy an array to a pointer. What **exactly** do you want to accomplish?  See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot copy a string into a character pointer, but you can copy a string to a memory block pointed to by a character pointer. You cannot do this:

```
char *ptr;
functionA(ptr);
```

and expect `ptr` to point to the string. You need to pass a pointer to a valid memory block into your function, like this:

```
char buf[100];
functionA(buf);
```

Now the copy would work, but the function would be unsafe because it wouldn't know how much memory is available for writing its string, and could cause buffer overruns. A better approach is to pass the size of the buffer along with the buffer:

```
functionA(buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Another alternative is to pass a pointer to pointer, and have the function allocate the string dynamically. In this case, however, the caller is responsible for freeing the memory after its use:

```
char *ptr;
functionA(&ptr);
...
free(ptr);
...
int functionA(char **fdate) {
    char date[20] = "20 May 2016";
    *fdate = malloc(sizeof(date));
    memcpy(*fdate, date);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have added code sample for FunctionB too. Please help me in this case

Comment: @shim_mang What's wrong with `FunctionB`? I don't understand "globally access" in the "The content of character array should be copied to character pointer fdate to globally access in functionB" statement.